# Logging in Unable to get past login screen

Tags: php, bolt-cms

When I type my credentials into the Bolt admin login screen, the page just reloads. I end up back on the login page with no error message or anything. I thought maybe I had my username/password wrong, so I tried changing them. When I do that, I get the "bad username/password" error. Here's a screen capture that shows what's happening: https://s3.amazonaws.com/twork/bolt-login.mov.

There was a time this was happening to me before, so I logged in with a different browser. That worked then, but it didn't work this time. When that happened, I saw that login attempts were logged on the Bolt dashboard page even the ones that took me back to the login page.

I've tried clearing my browser cache. I've also tried to log in using two other browsers, but that didn't work this time. I'm on Bolt 3.2.5. Is this a cache issue on the server? I can SSH into the box and clear the cache manually if I knew which directories to empty.

Another thing that might be relevant: I created this Bolt setup on one VM, took a snapshot, then used the snapshot to build a new VM. However, this also happened to me even before I created the new VM. That is, this happened on the original VM as well as the new VM.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that there's some parts of the information that are used to create cookies, that are changing on your VM setup and that is leading to the cookie not being created correctly.

There are a few setting in `config.yml` that tweak the cookie settings, eg:

`cookies_use_remoteaddr: true
cookies_use_browseragent: false
cookies_use_httphost: true`

Try setting them all to false or change them one at a time to false.

The other thing to check is that the web server can write to the `app/cache` folder since that is where the session data is stored.

Comment: This fix is correct, and consistent with what the OP is seeing!

Comment: Also, in case it helps someone else I changed those two to false and was able to log in. I've switched them back to true since that's what the config file recommends. Was able to log out and log in again.

Comment: Last thing... The first time I tried to log in, I got a Bolt error. Something about changing the username, but I don't remember exactly what it was. If anyone runs into that, I just refreshed the login page and tried again. Went right to the dashboard after that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use bolt, but you would have to debug each step of the way to determine if your user login is in fact validated ok. `echo "here"; exit;` Also check if the session or cookie is set ok, etc. Some cms apps have a config debug mode setting to help with that. Good luck.